# Expand option on query

Tags: expand

Im writing multiple queries, I would like each query to be have its own expand/collapse option.

If I hit enter to start a new query, the new query gets added under the first queries expand button.

Comment: What tools are you using? What have you tried? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which programming language is this question about?